# How to upgrade Joomla 1.6 betas?

Tags: joomla

Greetings,
I'm starting a new site with joomla 1.6 b9, hoping that by early next year a stable release will be available.

I want to upgrade the Joomla 1.6 b9 to 1.6 b11. however I can't find upgrade instructions.

Cheers

Comment: This would be better asked at the [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 1):

Joomla's site is full of warnings like this:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: This is a beta version and is not intended to run any type of production site. It is intended to be used for evaluation purposes only.

so you really need to know what you're doing if you're going to be running pre-release software that has potential for changing APIs and database structures.

There is [one mention](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2145848#p2145848) by Andrew Eddie in the 1.6 Beta thread about updates:

> Our tradition is that there is a path to upgrade between betas but it will not be automated. Database diff's are generally provided if required and upgrading files should be a matter of overwriting the old ones. I doubt we'll provide file diff's during the beta period.

As you can see in the b11 distribution, there is a joomla_update_16b2.sql file in the `installation/sql/mysql` folder, so hopefully this advice held true and there are no database changes, in which case you'd just have to replace the files (making sure to preserve any of your own code).